# Keep the value of an already selected radio/select option

Tags: php, forms

I did a sign up form and what I need is that if the user who wants to register on this form makes a mistake on a field like on the password/confirm password and then presses the submit button it will be displayed as an error that the password and the confirm password fields do not match

But i want to keep data in  the already completed forms. 
I succeed keep the input type=text completed like this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])){ echo $_POST['username'];}?>"/>
```

But in my sign up form i have an security question topic and in these topic is put in  `<select><option>` tags. I want to keep the value selected if it was selected but it does not working:

```
<select name="questions" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['questions'])){ echo $_POST['questions'];}?>">
<option value="">- Pick a question from below -</option>
<option value="1">What was the name of your first pet ?</option>
</select>
```

And the same problem i get with `input type=radio`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I just finished now and it works. Thank you! I figure it out now how to do this with type=radio, you was really helpfull.

Comment: Glad to be of help @Filip

Comment: I finished add this code to a birthday topic :| @DhruvJoshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value is not a valid attribute for `<Select>` tag.
The check has to be made at each `<option>` tag level for the `selected` attribute.

```
<select name="questions" >
<option value="">- Pick a question from below -</option>
<option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['questions']) && $_POST['questions'] =='1'){ echo selected}?>>What was the name of your first pet ?</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `selected="selected"` in the desired option:

```
<select name="questions">
<option <?php if( ( isset($_POST['questions']) ) && ( $_POST['questions'] == '- Pick a question from below -') ) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>- Pick a question from below -</option>
...
</select>
```